# The legitimacy of the Hebrew Name of Allah SWT

Tags: asma-ul-husna

Is it permissible to call upon ALLAH SWT by His Hebraic Name YAHUWAH? Etymologically the Name means "I Am He Who Lives/Cause to live". This is similar to One of The 99 Names which Is al-Hayy. We know of four names in the Qur'an which are contracted with YAHUWAH due to their Hebraic origins, they are YAHudi, Elias/EliYAH AS, ZakarYAH AS and YAHya AS. Has there been any scholarly verdict on this?

Answer (score 4):

יהוה‎ being a revealed name of Allah, its meaning being the same as  الحي, and the names of the prophets being derived from it - are fair speculations but not 100% confirmed.

It is possible that it is a legitimate name of Allah but it is also possible that it is not. If there is anything in the previous scriptures which is not explicitly confirmed in our religion, then its authenticity (whether it is  divine or a corruption) is not verifiable and it is not a viable proof in our religion. We have been instructed to disregard it without confirming or denying it and to follow only what has been given to us (i.e. the Quran).

> ما حدثكم أهل الكتاب فلا تصدقوهم، ولا تكذبوهم
>
> Whatever the people of the Book tell you, do not verify them, nor falsify them.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/167) and [Abi Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/26/4)</sup>

> لقد جئتكم بها بيضاء نقية، لا تسألوهم عن شيء فيخبروكم بحق فتكذبوا به، أو بباطل فتصدقوا به
>
> [Summarized: *When Umar ibn al-Khatab brought a Jewsish scripture to the Prophet  ﷺ he disapproved of it and said:*]
>
> I have brought you something that is pure, do not ask the people of the Scripture about anything, lest they inform you of some truth and you deny it or that they tell you some falsehood and you confirm it.
>
> <sup>— [Musnad Ahmad](https://al-maktaba.org/book/13157/14934#p1)</sup>

Further regarding the names of Allah, many scholars do not accept using a name for Allah which is not proven in the Quran and Hadith:

> وذروا الذين يلحدون في أسمائه
>
> And leave those who practice deviation concerning His names.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 7:180](http://quran.com/7/180)</sup>

> وقال أهل المعاني: الإلحاد في أسماء الله تسميته بما لم يتسم به ولم ينطق به كتاب الله ولا سنة رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم
>
> And the people of interpretation say: Deviation in the names of Allah is naming Him with what is not present in the Book of Allah nor in the Sunnah of the Messenger of Allah ﷺ,
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Baghawy](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/baghawy/sura7-aya180.html#baghawy)</sup>
>
> قال ابن العربي: فحذار منها، ولا يدعون أحدكم إلا بما في كتاب الله والكتب الخمسة، وهي البخاري ومسلم والترمذي وأبو داود والنسائي. فهذه الكتب التي يدور الإسلام عليها، وقد دخل فيها ما في الموطأ الذي هو أصل التصانيف، وذروا ما سواها
>
> Ibn al-Arabi said: Beware of it, and let not anyone of you call upon Him using a name except one which is in the Book of Allah and the five books, which are Bukhari, Muslim, Tirmidhi, Abu Dawud and Nisa'i ... and leave everything else.
>
> <sup>— [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura7-aya180.html#qortobi)</sup>

Comment: The Tawrat is part of the Book of Allah SWT, even the Zabur, Injil and other revelations known or unknown. So by definition the Name is scriptural right? As for 7:180, the Tafsirs already explained it [here](https://quranx.com/tafsirs/7.180).

Comment: The Book of Allah means the Quran. Any part of the the Torah, Zabur or Injil which is not confirmed in the Quran and Sunnah is not verifiable and not applicable to us. I have answered your question rest it is upto you whether you accept it or not, we are not here to have a discussion.

Answer (score -1):

First of all the name "Yahweh" is NOT a proper name of God. It was a title given by ancient Israelities to different Gods.

See these links:-

https://enslavedbyfaith.com/gods-of-the-bible/

The proper Hebrew name for God is "Elohim" or "Eloah" equivalent to Arabic "Allah". Yahweh is title that was given to various gods, I think.

Comment: It's somewhat off to support an argument from secular atheistic sites that are as critical toward any religion, including Islam, as they are toward Judaism.

Comment: @Afiq - I have edited my answer and removed one of the links. The one link that I mentioned contains no anti-Islamic content at all. I am a Muslim myself and I take anti-Islamic content very seriously and try my best to never site any kind of garbage websites that attacks my own beloved religion of Islam even in the slightest manner. May Allah curse those who write such kind of garbage anti-Islamic content. This is why now I always investigate before citing my sources in my answer. May Allah protect us all. Ameen.

Comment: are you kidding me? Enslavebyfaith is also an anti-religion site.

Comment: @Afiq - First of all, who told you that I believe in that website? I am only using this site as a reference to expose the lie that "Yahweh" is a proper name of God Almighty when the fact remains that there is evidence that suggests that it is not the name of God Almighty. It was rather used by pagans in the Israelite/Palestinian region. This is why it is NOT suitable for a person to use this name for Allah Almighty. "Ya hayu" is the proper name of Allah Almighty. "enslavedbyfaith" does not contain any anti-Islamic content. If it does, then please point that out and I will remove this website.